# read -s gives error via script

Tags: terminal, password, input, read, konsole

I am trying to read a password from user, i used `-s` silent flag but `read -s` is not working from the script but it works if i do it manually from terminal.

error details

```
project.sh: 3: read: Illegal option -s
you entered
```

code

```
maddy@ElementalX:~/Desktop$ cat project.sh 
#!/usr/bin/sh

read -s -p "Enter Password: " pswd
echo "you entered $pswd"
maddy@ElementalX:~/Desktop$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-s` option to the built-in utility `read` is not a standard option, and is unlikely to be implemented in `sh`.  Likewise, the `-p` option for giving a custom prompt is unlikely to be implemented by a generic `sh`.

Run your script with `bash` instead, whose `read` does support `-s` for reading from the terminal without echoing the typed-in characters (and also `-p`).  The easiest way to do this is to change the `#!`-line to point to the `bash` executable on your system.

In a non-`bash` shell, you may get a similar effect with

```
printf 'Enter password: ' >&2

stty -echo
read password
stty echo
```

Comment: it's working now, but i just want to clear what's wrong with ```sh``` only ?? because same thing was working if i do it directly from terminal.

Comment: @MadhusudanBabar  Your `sh` is not `bash`, and its `read` does not implement `-s` nor `-p`.  Your shell in the terminal is `bash`, so it supports `read -s`.